# PHP Class Reference to Parent Variable

Tags: php, oop, subclass

I'm building an API service and have a parent class:

```
classAPI {
    public responseCode = "";
    public responseMessageLog ="";
    function run{
        // here I call my user auth class
        $oUser = new classUser(...);
    }
}
```

Inside my classUser I do a bunch of stuff and then write a bunch of variables: responseMessageLog (which is running log of where the script went) and responseCode (which is set to 0 or 1 or whatever depending on success or failure or warning).

I need to access my responseCode and responseMessageLog variables from within my User class and my parent API class, but I don't really want to be passing these variables into each child class and then passing them back. I would like it that when I update the variable in the child class it updates everywhere in all my class.... kind of like a global variable would... but I know that's not a good idea.

How have others stopped passing variables down the rabbit trail of classes.

in this class I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing dependencies isn't a rabbit hole you want to avoid--it makes for more testable code.   However, you don't need to pass every property, you can pass the parent object.

In your case just pass the `classAPI` object into the constructor of the `classUser` and in the constructor assign it to property.  The `classAPI` properties are public so you can access them in an instance of `classUser`.

```
 ClassAPI {
     public $responseCode = "";
     public $responseMessageLog ="";

     public function run{
         // here I call my user auth class
         $oUser = new ClassUser($this, ...);
      }
  }

 ClassUser {
     public $myClassApi = null;

     public function __construct(ClassAPI $myClassApi) {

         $this->myClassApi = $myClassApi;
      }

     public function someFunction() {
         echo $this->myClassApi->responseCode;
     }

   }
```

Added notes:

- In case it comes up in another answer, don't use static properties to do what you're trying to do.
- Capitalize your class names.
- In production code I might add an initialization function in `ClasUser` instead passing the `ClassAPI` directly into the constructor.

Comment: can I call methods like this as well?

Comment: @NathanLeggatt if they're public visibility (not private or protected)

Comment: doesn't appear to see my methods that are in the parent class

Comment: @Nathan parent class? Not sure what you mean, no child classes your example.  Using my example,  if you had a function `foo()` in ClassAPI you'd be able to call from the `someFunction()` method of the ClassUser with `$this->myClassApi->foo()` assuming `foo()` is public.